# Nodejs cluster isn't response to web browser

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie in Nodejs and I try something with cluster on nodejs. But I meet a problem:
- I use example on Nodejs API about Cluster:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case its a HTTP server
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
  }).listen(8000);
}
```

- I run above code, but when hit url into browser (localhost:8000), browser doesn't receive any response from nodejs (it's connecting... forever until I kill nodejs @@), I am,however, getting the "online" event to fire.

How can I get this server to respond to requests?

p/s: I try getting event "exit" to respawn new worker. Sometime when I hit enter on browser, console log worker x die and then respawn new worker. But browser still connecting...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHSYY.png

Help me :) and sorry my bad english

I install the newest version of nodejs ( v0.10.24)

Comment: what is the version of node?

Comment: My node is v0.10.24, the newest version on http://nodejs.org/ @@

Comment: Just tested, and it works fine for me?

Comment: how are you running this code?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RHSYY.png => I capture an image :D I just using cmd and move to code folder. And run with command node test.js (test.js is code above)

Comment: As this is a pretty basic example, I think you need to post an issue on node repo.

Comment: Have you tried running the script without `cluster` (so just the `http.createServer(...)` part)?

Comment: if I running script without cluster, everything work fine :(

Comment: @Quảng Is there an anti-virus program that not allow your program to fork new processes - disable all anti-virus programs?

Comment: @damphat: I only use Microsoft Security Essentials. I try disabled Real Time Protection of MSE and disable Firewall, but my program doesn't work :((

Comment: :| I don't understand :(( I try that code on friend's computer, It work :( but in my computer it doesn't work @@

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with cluster. Try putting the http server creation part inside a setTimeout call. (for example delay it for 1000 ms) you should observe an improvement.

```
setTimeout(function(){ http.createServer...... }, 1000);
```

Besides, you may also try to create your server using [jxcore](http://jxcore.com) mt-keep to see if it works on the similar case.

```
$ jx mt-keep servercode.js
```